# how to modify this xml having 2 buttons?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am trying to place button and button icon with textview representing count at top right. two buttons should be in horizontal alignment. icon button should occupy fixed space on right. other button should take remaining space.
I am attaching my xml. 
How to modify that xml

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/snow"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Want a Samyata Personal Shopper to find it for you?"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:background="#909be7"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppinsmedium"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/listcount"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bag" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listcount"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_red"
                android:id="@+id/text_count"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="0 Items in cart"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just covered `RelativeLayout`

for example,

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bag" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/back"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/circle_red"
        android:id="@+id/text_count"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0 Items in cart"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

p.s]

circle_red.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#ff5722"/>
    <corners android:radius="100dp"/>
</shape>
```

and it show like this.

p.s] make center using LinearLayout.

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/snow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#909be7"
            android:text="Want a Samyata Personal Shopper to find it for you?"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/listcount"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_count"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="-10dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listcount"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle_red"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="0 Items in cart"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: can you post your xml? "0 Items in cart" text is showing right top now. or can you describe what you want?

Comment: no need . just adjusted. everything is working fine

Comment: hey, i had another xml doubt .pls verify my below code @ST

Comment: hi, you have place icon in center . but it should be fixed at right @ST

Comment: two buttons should be in same line only. icon button fixed space at right . remaining space for other button @ST

Comment: can you pls change that @S T

Comment: add `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` in "0 Items in cart" text view